# is_logged_in function always return false for http://domain.com/wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

`is_logged_in()` function always return false

I believe it is because the wordpress is hosted in sub domain due to which cookies do not get the correct path.

So i tried using `define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', './wordpress');` in wp-config.php

It is not working.

Am I setting the cookie right?

Please help !!

Comment: Are you using a multi-network setup?

Comment: Nope i have a domain in that i have a folder which contains wordpress files eg http://domain.com/wordpress , domain.com is the domain and wordpress is a folder in the domain domain.com

Comment: how can i check if user is logged in ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
} else {
    echo 'Welcome, visitor!';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but that did not work .. it is displaying "welcome visitor" even if i am logged in